# How to make cloth fit body

Tags: mesh

How or what skill to make cloth fit a specific body?

[image: This is cloth]
[image: This is cloth with body]

Comment: Is this an animation or just a pose?

Comment: Currently this is just a pose, later we will make it animate, to make the cloth rig with body is another question.

Comment: I am figuring it out that the sculpt tool and function may help, but it is too much manual & visual work, and result is not perfect. I guess there should be some tool much more automatic.